# Fix background-color td table

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the layout of these tables. One table have 3 columns, the other 2.

The "colspan" values match and are correct (30) and each "TD" has a set width, but purple color is also over green. (You can notice it by zoomming the page at 300%).

Of course, the problem is solved if I add a new column to Table 2, correcting colspan and width it.

Are there other ways to solve this problem?

Thank you!

```html
<table style="width: 60px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgba(160,141,163,0.5); border-spacing: 0px; position: absolute;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color: rgba(196, 110, 239, 0.28); width: 36px; height: 1px;" colspan="18"></td>
   <td style="background-color: rgba(143, 254, 163, 0.5); width: 22px; height: 1px;" colspan="11"></td>
   <td style="width: 2px; height: 1px;" colspan="1"></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<table style="width: 60px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgba(173,180,179,0.5); border-spacing: 0px; position: absolute;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color: rgba(196, 110, 239, 0.28); width: 36px; height: 1px;" colspan="18"></td>
   <td style="width: 24px; height: 1px;" colspan="12"></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: can you put an image of what you expected?

Comment: Image added, if you see the purple color is over green

Comment: "Both have two rows, one of them has 3 columns while the other 2." No they do not, they only have 1 row. `<tr> ` is table row. You only have 1 `<tr></tr>` in each table meaning you have only 1 row in each table.

Comment: Stupid question, but why does the table have 30 columns if it only has 3 columns? Also, if I put it in a fiddle, I don't see any "grey area" where the cells are supposedly overlapping, not even when I zoom in.

Comment: The row is 60px wide and 30 columns deep. The purple is 36px wide , 18 cols deep : **60%**/ The green is 22px and 11 cols : 37%. Then the white is 2px 1 col: 3%. What use is having 30 cols when 3 should suffice?

Comment: I use 30 cols in this example because i have a table with 300 rows and 400 columns afflicted by this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

**First:** Colspan really has nothing to do with the problem you're having, however I don't fully understand your intent with colspan here.  With only 1 row per table, colspan really isn't doing anything.

**Second:** When using fixed width columns, use `table-layout:fixed` on your table element.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

**Third:** This is most likely why you're having issues: Table cells (`<td>`) by default have some padding which is going to visually decrease the width of all cells the more cells you have in the table (when using fixed widths).  Which is why your first table (having 3 columns) appears to have a smaller first cell than your second table (only having 2 columns). The other 2 cells are forcing it smaller due to their padding.  Setting `padding: 0` on these cells can eliminate that.

**Fourth:** Your fixed widths on the tables don't add up because you're not considering the left and right border on the table which adds another 2px. For example you defined the first table as **60px** wide

- Col 1 = 36
- Col 2 = 22
- Col 3 = 2
- Left + right border = 2

**Total actual width = 62px**

Fixed tables demo (using CSS, cause those inline styles are killing my eyes).

```css
table {
 table-layout: fixed;
 width: 60px;
 height: 40px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(173,180,179,0.5);
 border-spacing: 0;
 position: absolute;
}
table tr td {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

table tr td:nth-child(1) {
 background-color: rgba(196, 110, 239, 0.28);  width: 34px;
}

table tr td:nth-child(2) {
 background-color: rgba(143, 254, 163, 0.5); 
}
table.table1 tr td:nth-child(2) {
 width: 22px;
}
table.table2 tr td:nth-child(2) {
 width: 24px;
}

table.table1 tr td:nth-child(3) {
 background-color: rgba(196, 110, 239, 0.28); 
 width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table class='table1'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class='table2'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```